# Killer AX1650 wifi very slow on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.04

I just bought a new Gigabyte Aero 15 Oled which come with windows 10 and full Intel chipsets. But what a surprise, when I setup Ubuntu 19.04 (19.10 don't even show boot screen, but that's another issue...) the wifi chipset is not detected.

I searched on the internet for a while an found some suggestions about this wifi issue.

I installed the Killer AX 1650 driver from PPA as explained on their website : https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/

So now it's detected but I lost connection randomly and on reconnect (or at first connection) it can have a capped connection speed to 1mb/s, somethimes more (saw 21, 56...) instead of the full speed (>850Mb/s) it can have on windows (and sometimes on linux too).

Despite using lastest kernel (5.0.0-36-generic) and test each solution described in this tutorial (which resume most of the differents solutions I found on other websites) I keep having random slow signal : https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/

Another detail than can be related is that I have ramdom kworker using 100 cpu, when it happens I must hard restart the laptop as I lost bluetooth (but can still change workspaces and run commands without sudo)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update : I couldn't resolve the issue with the officials drivers (even from sources).
I end up upgrading ubuntu to 19.10 and removed the official drivers, my card was recognised imediatly and works at full speed.

So simple fix is : upgrade your system.